# Rails removing a column from activerecord not working

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I want to remove `container:references` from my table, I have tried:

`rails generate migration RemoveContainerfromCreateTasks container:references`

followed by `rails db:migrate`, but it my reference field is still not removed.

Below is my ActiveRecord

```
class CreateTasks < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :tasks do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :body
      t.references :container, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.text :tag
      t.datetime :due
      t.integer :priority

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end


class RemoveContainerfromCreateTasks < ActiveRecod::Migration[6.1]
    def change
    end
end
```

Comment: What does the `RemoveContainerfromCreateTasks` migration that is generated look like? That might give you some insight into why it's not working. Can you add it to the question?

Comment: @Josien added it

Comment: Ah well, that explains a lot, this migration is not doing anything :-D You can do a rollback of this migration first (`rails db:rollback`), and then add something like `remove_column :tasks, :container` to the migrations `change` function, save, and migrate again.

Comment: Ah, and I think that the reason that this was not properly detected by Rails when generating the migration for you is that your model is called `CreateTasks` and the table is called `tasks`, could that be it?

Comment: How do I know if my table is called tasks or task?

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit confused by the `RemoveContainerfromCreateTasks` migration. Your table is called `tasks`, as is shown in the `CreateTasks` migration - it says `create_table :tasks`. You generated a migration with this command: `rails generate migration RemoveContainerfromCreateTasks container:references`, and that implies that the table is called `CreateTasks`. I think that confused Rails. You could try to generate the migration that you want by running `rails generate migration RemoveContainerFromTasks container:references`. Or fix the migration you already have. Does this help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is really a sneaky capitalization error. Running:

```
rails generate migration RemoveContainerfromCreateTasks container:references
```

Will generate a migration with an empty change block which will do absolutely nothing when you migrate it except modify the migrations meta table (a table that AR uses to keep track of which migrations have been run). But if you properly capitalize `From`:

```
rails generate migration RemoveContainerFromCreateTasks container:references
```

It will generate:

```
class RemoveContainerFromCreateTasks < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    remove_reference :create_tasks, :container, null: false, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

Rails isn't actually intelligent. It just casts the name argument into snake case and compares it to a set of patterns like:

```
remove_something_from_tablename foo:string bar:integer
create_tablename foo:string bar:integer
create_foo_bar_join_table foo bar
```

And it then uses a template to generate the according type of migration. If you don't properly pluralize it will be cast into:

```
remove_containerfrom_create_tasks
```

Which Rails does not know what to do with as it does not match a known pattern.

Also note despite popular belief migrations are just a DSL to create SQL transformations which is completely unaware about your tables or models. In this case the resulting migration will just blow up when you attempt to run it since you don't have a `create_tasks` table.

I would roll the missnamed migration back. Delete it then run:

```
rails g migration RemoveContainerFromTasks container:references
rails db:migrate
```

Comment: I find it easier to type migrations and model/controller names correctly using snake_case instead.

Comment: can I delete the new class RemoveContainerFromTasks after i ran `db:migrate`?

Comment: Normally you would run the migration against your production environment too.

Answer (score -1):

Your issue here is that "CreateTasks" is not table in your database.  "Tasks" is, however.

```
rails g migration RemoveContainerFromTasks container:references
```

will provide you

```
class RemoveContainerFromTasks < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    remove_reference :tasks, :container, null: false, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

A migration of this will successfully remove *container* from your schema.rb file, and subsequently the database system you're using.

Here's some console output, because why not:

```
unclecid@home:~/Desktop/sample_app$ rails db:migrate
== 20201227150512 CreateTasks: migrating ======================================
-- create_table(:tasks)
   -> 0.0022s
== 20201227150512 CreateTasks: migrated (0.0023s) =============================

== 20201227151021 RemoveContainerFromTasks: migrating =========================
-- remove_reference(:tasks, :container, {:null=>false, :foreign_key=>true})
   -> 0.0330s
== 20201227151021 RemoveContainerFromTasks: migrated (0.0331s) ================
```

Comment: Rails does not actually care if you use the right table name as migrations are just a DSL and they are not aware of tables or models. Try `rails g migration remove_foo_from_bar foo:string` if you want an example of this as it will generate the same migration no matter if the table or model exists or not.

Comment: I didn't even notice the non-capitalized 'f' in from.  Two typos for the OP.